# how to store a maya nodes hierarchy into a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, maya, autodesk

[Click here for view the example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86tnu.jpg)

I need to get the hierarchy Data or store it into a dictionary from the outliner panel from Maya in the right order, how can i archive this ? , im working in autodesk maya and only can be store into a dict for further used as a .json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my answer from this question:
[How to store and then retrive parent-child dependency data (Maya MEL/Python script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764093/how-to-store-and-then-retrive-parent-child-dependency-data-maya-mel-python-scri)

Basically, there's a recursive function in there that starts from the top node and goes through the hierarchy storing everything into a dict.

Once you have that dict, it should be very easy to spit out a json file.

There's also some code for re-parenting everything.

hope that helps!

Comment: you are the MAN! muchas gracias buen hombre :) you deserve a beer and ten more

Comment: glad I could help!